# How do I automatically tab to this element when the page loads

Tags: javascript, tabs

How do I automatically tab to this element and press enter when the page loads?
The element I am trying to use has this class `d2l-contextmenu-ph`, but I can't seem to tab to it.

```js
let msg = document.querySelector(".d2l-contextmenu-ph ");

msg.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
   alert("test");
});
```

```html
<div id="propertiesPlaceholderId" class="d2l-placeholder d2l-placeholder-live" aria-live="assertive">
                    <div id="d2l_1_69_681" class="d2l-floating-container d2l-hidden ">
                        <template id="OrgUnitEditorProviders$Plugins`1$PluginView$ouPropertiesContextMenu" class="d2l-contextmenu-template" data-floating-container-id="d2l_1_69_681" data-dropdown-content-id="d2l_1_70_789">
                        <d2l-menu class="d2l-menu-mvc d2l-contextmenu">
                            <d2l-menu-item text="Edit Properties" id="d2l_1_71_946"></d2l-menu-item>
                            <d2l-menu-item text="Delete Unit" id="d2l_1_72_494"></d2l-menu-item>
                        </d2l-menu>
                        </template>
                    </div><h3 class="d2l-heading vui-heading-3 d2l_1_73_408" id="OrgUnitEditorProviders$Plugins`1$PluginView$propertiesHeading">Properties</h3>
                    
          
                <d2l-dropdown-context-menu no-auto-open="" text="Actions for Org Unit Properties" id="d2l_1_74_921" class="d2l-contextmenu-ph d2l-contextmenu-ph-dropdown d2l_1_73_408" data-contextmenuid="OrgUnitEditorProviders$Plugins`1$PluginView$ouPropertiesContextMenu" data-placeholderkey="d2l_1_75_382">
                      
            
            <d2l-button-icon icon="tier1:chevron-down" text="Actions for Org Unit Properties" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" type="button" data-js-focus-visible="">
            <button class="d2l-label-text" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-label="Actions for Org Unit Properties" id="d2l-uid-22" title="Actions for Org Unit Properties" type="button"> <d2l-icon class="d2l-button-icon" icon="tier1:chevron-down">hh</d2l-icon>
            
            <d2l-icon class="d2l-button-icon" icon="tier1:chevron-down"></d2l-icon>
            
            </button>
            
            </d2l-button-icon>
            
                    </d2l-dropdown-context-menu>
          
          
          <d2l-dropdown-menu no-pointer="" align="start" min-width="200" max-width="370" vertical-offset="12" id="d2l_48_1_419" class="d2l-dropdown-menu-contextmenu" no-auto-focus="" no-padding="" dropdown-content="" opened="" style="--d2l-dropdown-verticaloffset:12px; left: 785.375px;"><d2l-menu class="d2l-menu-mvc d2l-contextmenu" label="Actions for Org Unit Properties" active="" aria-label="Actions for Org Unit Properties" role="menu" style="height: 107px;">
            <d2l-menu-item text="Edit Properties" id="d2l_48_2_483" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Edit Properties" first="true"></d2l-menu-item>
            <d2l-menu-item text="Delete Org Unit" id="d2l_48_3_770" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Delete Org Unit" last="true"></d2l-menu-item>
        </d2l-menu></d2l-dropdown-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object of any Event in you case keyboard event  and trigger it using [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

```js
let msg = document.querySelector(".d2l-contextmenu-ph ");


msg.addEventListener('keydown', e => {

console.log('I was clicked', e.keyCode)


})




// function to create keyboard event 
function createKeyboardEvent(options){
  return new KeyboardEvent('keydown', options);
}


// function to trigget any kind of event on the selected elem
function trigger(elem, event){
    elem.dispatchEvent(event)
}



const options = {
    bubbles: false, cancelable: true, keyCode: 13
}
const keyboardEvent = createKeyboardEvent(options)

trigger(msg, keyboardEvent)
```

```html
<div id="propertiesPlaceholderId" class="d2l-placeholder d2l-placeholder-live" aria-live="assertive">
                    <div id="d2l_1_69_681" class="d2l-floating-container d2l-hidden ">
                        <template id="OrgUnitEditorProviders$Plugins`1$PluginView$ouPropertiesContextMenu" class="d2l-contextmenu-template" data-floating-container-id="d2l_1_69_681" data-dropdown-content-id="d2l_1_70_789">
                        <d2l-menu class="d2l-menu-mvc d2l-contextmenu">
                            <d2l-menu-item text="Edit Properties" id="d2l_1_71_946"></d2l-menu-item>
                            <d2l-menu-item text="Delete Unit" id="d2l_1_72_494"></d2l-menu-item>
                        </d2l-menu>
                        </template>
                    </div><h3 class="d2l-heading vui-heading-3 d2l_1_73_408" id="OrgUnitEditorProviders$Plugins`1$PluginView$propertiesHeading">Properties</h3>
                    
          
                <d2l-dropdown-context-menu no-auto-open="" text="Actions for Org Unit Properties" id="d2l_1_74_921" class="d2l-contextmenu-ph d2l-contextmenu-ph-dropdown d2l_1_73_408" data-contextmenuid="OrgUnitEditorProviders$Plugins`1$PluginView$ouPropertiesContextMenu" data-placeholderkey="d2l_1_75_382">
                      
            
            <d2l-button-icon icon="tier1:chevron-down" text="Actions for Org Unit Properties" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" type="button" data-js-focus-visible="">
            <button class="d2l-label-text" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-label="Actions for Org Unit Properties" id="d2l-uid-22" title="Actions for Org Unit Properties" type="button"> <d2l-icon class="d2l-button-icon" icon="tier1:chevron-down">hh</d2l-icon>
            
            <d2l-icon class="d2l-button-icon" icon="tier1:chevron-down"></d2l-icon>
            
            </button>
            
            </d2l-button-icon>
            
                    </d2l-dropdown-context-menu>
          
          
          <d2l-dropdown-menu no-pointer="" align="start" min-width="200" max-width="370" vertical-offset="12" id="d2l_48_1_419" class="d2l-dropdown-menu-contextmenu" no-auto-focus="" no-padding="" dropdown-content="" opened="" style="--d2l-dropdown-verticaloffset:12px; left: 785.375px;"><d2l-menu class="d2l-menu-mvc d2l-contextmenu" label="Actions for Org Unit Properties" active="" aria-label="Actions for Org Unit Properties" role="menu" style="height: 107px;">
            <d2l-menu-item text="Edit Properties" id="d2l_48_2_483" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Edit Properties" first="true"></d2l-menu-item>
            <d2l-menu-item text="Delete Org Unit" id="d2l_48_3_770" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Delete Org Unit" last="true"></d2l-menu-item>
        </d2l-menu></d2l-dropdown-menu>
```

Comment: hmm it doesnt hightlight

Comment: @Vzupo you can use .foucs()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus

Comment: where would .focus go in the above code? because document.querySelector(".d2l-contextmenu-ph ").focus() doesnt work